# Disable command bar (top toolbar) in VMWare Workstation Full Screen

Tags: windows, vmware-workstation

Is there any way to enable fullscreen in VMWare Workstation (10.0) but disable the command bar? I know Exclusive Mode does this, but I want to keep <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> right click to switch VMs. I run tasks that require frequent switching, but the top command bar gets in the way - the one that comes down automatically when the cursor hits the top. Even moving it would be an improvement.

Comment: If answers from [this](http://superuser.com/questions/246644/can-i-completely-hide-toolbar-in-vmware-workstation) post doesn't work. Make sure you have it unpinned.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/Hmu0S.png