# How Can I completely hide toolbar in VMware Workstation 14 Player on a Linux Host?

Tags: virtual-machine, linux-mint, vmware-player

I have tried adding the line below to my Virtual Machines `.vmx` file as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/246644/can-i-completely-hide-toolbar-in-vmware-workstation/559146#559146) (this thread is meant for Windows Hosts though). However it isn't working. Any suggestion on how I can completely hide the toolbar? I don't want even a single pixel of it showing.

I am running VMware Workstation Player in Linux Mint 19.

```
pref.vmplayer.fullscreen.nobar = "TRUE"
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. The setting below should be added to `/home/user/.vmware/preferences`

```
pref.vmplayer.fullscreen.nobar="TRUE"
```